# Window.History.pushState not working if some http request is pending

Tags: javascript

I am having multiple tiles in my home page.One tile http request takes more time to load data and in between if user click on other tiles which are loaded then window.history.pushState() not adding new page entry to browser.Url changes to new page but as soon as my previous http respone which was pending gets completed my new url automatically changes to previous one.

I am using page transition effects.

`window.history.pushState({ path: url }, '', url);`
url is the new url of the page where i want to redirect

Comment: Is the `domain name` of new  url is same or different with previous one ?

Comment: domain same of both url.Url in browser also changes to new url and new page also gets loaded successfully.But as soon as my pending http request of previous page gets completed url again changes back to previous url

Comment: Please add all relevant code.

Comment: using this code https://codyhouse.co/gem/animated-page-transition/